# What is a group of dragonflies?

Tags: nouns, terminology, terms-of-venery

As per title, what is the name of a group of dragonflies? Some friends say it is a mob, some say it is a hover. Anyone?

Comment: Is "swarm" not applicable to dragonflies ?

Comment: Related: [Terms for collections of animals](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/).

Comment: a glimmer of dragonflies is the term I like to use

Comment: I would say a "squadron".

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-group-of-dragons-called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A flight or cluster of dragonflies :)

Comment: Thanks mate. A quick google search for those proved your answer correct. I guess I didn't know what to search in the first place. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Search for "collective noun animal wiki".

Comment: It's worth pointing out that these collective nouns have a very artificial history compared to that of most words. Most of them first appeared in The Book of St Albans in about 1500 and wasn't what you'd call a book of great learning, it was full of humour, lore, and arbitrary assertions. Not that these are bad things, but students shouldn't get too hung up on learning the more obscure collective, unless they are inclined to do so, as they have very little currency.

Answer (score 4):

A large or dense group of flying insects is called a **[swarm](https://www.lexico.com/definition/swarm)**.

You could also say *a bunch of dragonflies*.

Answer (score 4):

The Ngram of "[a * of dragonflies](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20*%20of%20dragonflies&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20swarm%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20pair%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20couple%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ca%20*%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20swarm%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20pair%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20couple%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0)" shows only three results: *swarm*, *pair* and *couple*.

I've also looked at how *swarm* compares to other suggestions so far (e.g., *flight, cluster, beauty, cloud, bunch, glimmer, squadron, mob, hover*) in [another Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20swarm%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20flight%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20cluster%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20beauty%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20cloud%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20bunch%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20glimmer%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20squadron%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20mob%20of%20dragonflies%2Ca%20hover%20of%20dragonflies&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20swarm%20of%20dragonflies%3B%2Cc0), which shows that Ngrams are not found for any of the other suggestions.

Therefore, I think you should go with *swarm*.

Answer (score 3):

According to Smithsonian magazine, the term is "swarm."

See [fact number 12](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/14-fun-facts-about-dragonflies-96882693/) about dragonflies.

Yet National Geographic mentions the terms "flight" and "cluster". See [this page](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/invertebrates/d/dragonflies-insects/) on dragonflies.

I gather that the three most accepted terms are "swarm", "flight", and "cluster".

Answer (score 2):

Beauty. Used in the book, The Bees, by Laline Paul, she describes a group of dragonflies as "a beauty of dragonflies."

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, *a [**cloud** of dragonflies](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cloud+of+dragonflies%22&biw=491&bih=323&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnq-C3z6_MAhVEzRQKHevdA28Q_AUICygG)*

> cloud
>
> : a large number of things (such as insects) that move together through the air in a group
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloud)