# What is a group of fish?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Terms for collections of animals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/terms-for-collections-of-animals)

What is a group of fish called?

Comment: Flagging this to be closed as "general reference".

Comment: In addition to _school_, there are a handful of other words used for specific species: [fish collective nouns](http://www.myuniversalfacts.com/2006/08/collective-nouns-for-fish-what-group.html).

Answer (score 5):

A group of fish is called a **school** or a **shoal**.

Comment: Please, comment what you disapprove of when you downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It's known as a *shoal* or a *school*.