# Are any of these collective nouns hoaxes?

Tags: collective-nouns, terms-of-venery

[image]

While some of these are unquestionably used (a clowder of cats, a pack of dogs), many just surprise me. For example “a cackle of hyenas”, “a memory of elephants”... For the latter I found a confirming article, namely [this](http://www.everywordcounts.co.uk/collective-nouns-for-animals/) one.

Edit: I realise the impracticality of going through each word in the list. That’s why I reworded to “any” almost immediately. I expected that native speakers would quickly recognise at least one construction, for instance “a cackle of hyenas”, as a hoax. Although I have been an avid reader of English prose for decades, I had no idea about the origins of venery and that it was actually meant to be funny!

Comment: Closely related: [Are 'streak' and 'ambush' really the collective nouns for tigers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226378/are-streak-and-ambush-really-the-collective-nouns-for-tigers/226380#226380).

Comment: Related: [Etymology of “a pride of lions”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221686/etymology-of-a-pride-of-lions) and [A murder of crows?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/a-murder-of-crows)

Comment: A large proportion of *all* terms of venery are "hoaxes" in that they were inventions of clever authors, not terms in common usage, e.g. *an impatience of wives* and *an unhappiness of husbands*. *[The Boke of Saint Albans](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/63241)* and all that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Do the supposed duplicates explain the meaning and usage of “cackle  of hyenas”?

Comment: @user159691 the user gave that as one of two examples of a possible hoax. I also see an enormous list of collection nouns. What about you? What about checking a "wisdom of wombats" or a "bloat of hippos"? And.... the answer is that many of these terms were created for fun. It's in the answers posted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - that, toghether with “memory of elephants” is what the question is about. But, who cares.

Comment: @user159691 `They are terms of venery, which means that they are quite likely to have been made up just to be a bit funny and act as linguistic curios` **and** `There is another piece of circumstantial evidence: terms of venery in English are often quite transparently meant to be amusing or exaggerated gibes at perceived characteristics of the animal in question. ` **and** `It was lingual fun. The trend developed in the middle of the 15th century and one of the first such lists occurs in The Bokys of Haukyng ... better known as Boke of Seynt Albans or The Book of St. Albans printed 1486.`

Comment: @Mari-LouA that’s why I reworded the question to “any”. Obviously you are not supposed to check all of them. The hope was that one of them be identified as a hoax.

Comment: The answer is more than one, and I wouldn't call them "hoaxes" they are terms created by just a bunch of English nuns (if I remember correctly) playing around with words. Better to call them jokes and word association games.

Comment: @Ludi - it is an  interesting question, only apparently a duplicate. You could fix it asking about a few specific usages like hyena etc. referring to the past questions for the general nature of the terms of venery.

Comment: @user159691 thank you! Of what exactly is it a duplication? I only saw the questions about streak, ambush, pride and murder. These being legitimate does not imply none of the above are hoaxes - although the answers teach us the essentials of venery. Perhaps I should edit to “contemporary hoaxes”?

Comment: A grumble of grammarians grimace.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the following g terms are actually used, known as “terms of venery”

As for cackle, the following extract from  [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-packs-of-hyenas-called-and-why) comments:

> There is also a poetic term, ***'a cackle of hyenas***', but this is very rarely used, much like 'a dazzle of zebras' - no zoologist would use these terms. They would say 'a clan of hyenas' and 'a herd of zebras'.

***[Memory of Elephants](http://www.everywordcounts.co.uk/collective-nouns-for-animals/)***

Comment: I would naturally say a pack of hyenas myself.

Comment: @tchrist - I would say a *laughter* of hyenas.

Comment: I've always called the gang nearby a *Titter* of hyenas.